# Java mail charset ISO-8859-2 not working

Tags: java, internationalization, jakarta-mail, iso-8859-2

I am having problem with Java Mail API.

I can successfully send mail, but some special characters (from ISO-8859-2 languages like czech, slovak) are not shown in mail. They are damaged even in IDE output.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-2")
```

Comment: any reason not to use commons-email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, using multipart. here is code :

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
MimeBodyPart tmpBp = new MimeBodyPart();
tmpBp.setContent(message,"text/plain; charset=utf-8");
multipart.addBodyPart(tmpBp);
msg.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

msg.setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

instead of the charset you've given?

Answer (score 0):

Rather use `UTF-8` as charset and configure your IDE console to use the very same charset as well. I don't know which IDE you're using as you didn't tell about it, but if it were Eclipse, then you can change it by *Window* > *Preferences* > *General* > *Workspace* > *Text file encoding* > *Other* > *UTF-8*.

If that doesn't fix the problem, then the problem lies somewhere else. Maybe you're reading the message from a file using the wrong encoding. For that you need to use [`InputStreamReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) which takes the charset as 2nd constructor argument.

Comment: I tried UTF-8
The weird thing is that it works in IDE (NetBeans) when I manually set println (System.out.println("Some text using special chars"); shows ok .... but I made output to IDE of message which is sent and that output is damaged :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `setText` method from the class `MimeMessage` instead of `setContent`

```
/**
     * Convenience method that sets the given String as this part's
     * content, with a MIME type of "text/plain" and the specified
     * charset. The given Unicode string will be charset-encoded
     * using the specified charset. The charset is also used to set
     * the "charset" parameter.
     *
     * @param   text    the text content to set
     * @param   charset the charset to use for the text
     * @exception   MessagingException  if an error occurs
     */
    public void setText(String text, String charset)
            throws MessagingException {
```